# MongoDB - Remove Folder

Tags: mongodb, directory

I'm trying to delete all folders on MongoDB whose descriptions contain a number higher than 10. Can you tell me how to do that?
I've been trying desperately since hours... 
Thanks very much!

[Robomongo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yyBZ8.png)

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a mechanism to get a list of the keys in the collection first, filter the list for the ones that have a number greater than 10 and then generate a query that you will use with the **[`$unset`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/update/unset/)** operator in your update. Your update document should have this structure:

```
var update = {
    "$unset": {
        "p11": "",
        "p12": "",
        ...
    }
}
```

which you will use in your update as

```
db.collection.update({}, update, {multi: true});
```

You need the **[`mapReduce()`](https://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/method/db.collection.mapReduce/#db.collection.mapReduce)** command to generate that update document. The following mapreduce operation will populate a separate collection with the document as the value:

```
db.collection.mapReduce(
    function() {
        var map = this;
        for (var key in map) { 
            if (map.hasOwnProperty(key)){
                num = parseInt(key.replace(/[^\d.]/g, '' ));
                if (num > 10) emit(null, key); 
            }
        }
    },
    function(key, values) {
        return values.reduce(function(o, v) {
            o[v] = "";
            return o;
        }, {});      
    }, 
    { "out": "filtered_keys" }
);
```

You can then run a query on the resultant collection to get the update document and do the actual update:

```
var update = {
        "$unset": db.filtered_keys.findOne({"_id": null}).value
    },
    options = { "multi": true };
db.collection.update({}, update, options);
```

Comment: Hi chridam, works great!! Thank you very much, saved my day :-)

Comment: @Mike8989 No worries, happy to help :)